# Referring to Dataset Allocated in REXX

Tags: mainframe, jcl, rexx, tso

We have a REXX program  which creates a dataset **LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT** saves in  DDNAME **LOGNM.**

We call the REXX PROGRAM from JCL using IKJEFT1B utility.

How do I use this dataset for further processing in JCL. I mean how I refer it in the JCL since the dataset name is dynamically created.

Comment: Some JCL and Rexx would be handy

Answer (score 2):

Are you **creating** the dataset in the Rexx program using **TSO Allocate** or **TSO Copy** command 
or similar TSO commands ???

- If you are then you have a **problem**, you will **not** be able to reference 
  the dataset saftely in following steps (There are methods that will work in some versions of JES).
  I would suggest you recode the rexx and allocate data set in the JCL.

```
       //LOGNM    DD  DSN=LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT,DISP=(NEW,CATLG), ....
```

- If you alread allocate the dataset using JCL i.e with a DD statement like

```
       //LOGNM    DD  DSN=LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT,DISP=(NEW,CATLG), ....
```

or

```
       //LOGNM    DD  DSN=LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT,DISP=OLD
```

you should have no problem using the Dataset in following steps.

- If you allocate and delete the dataset using JCL i.e with a DD statement like

```
       //LOGNM    DD  DSN=LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT,DISP=(NEW,DELETE), ....
```

then change the DELETE to CATLG (or pass)

Comment: Thanks, we are using TSO Allocate for the dataset . I found that we cannot refer the dataset allocated in REXX, so instead I redirected the name of the dataset in a file allocated in JCL to use further.

Answer (score 1):

Once your dataset is created, you can refer to it in JCL exactly as you would any other dataset. It does not matter that it was created dynamically, as the dataset disposition is included when you create it. It gets processed exactly as though it were created with a JCL DD statement. I'm not aware that there is even an indication that it was created dynamically, once it has been created. It is no different from any other PS dataset.

If cataloged:

```
//SOMENAME DD DISP=SHR,DSN=LOG.DYYMMDD.THHMMSS.OUT
```

If not cataloged, catalog it, then see above.

If deleted when closed, don't delete it but catalog it, then see above.

Note: I have assumed that you are creating your dataset in one JOB and accessing it in others. If you are accessing it in the same JOB, take good note of Bruce Martin's answer. Your dataset will be "hidden", from the normal assessment of Disposition processing of the JOB when it is submitted because the dataset is only created *after* that point, when the JOB is actually running (if it gets as fair as running, it may fail immediately with a "JCL ERROR" without even getting close to running).

Personally I'd do it in separate JOBs, but some people think they are keeping things simple when they are not.